# Create Custom SharePoint Timer Jobs

Tags: sharepoint

I wrote code inside a Web Part and I want to move it into a custom SharePoint Timer job.

I read [this article](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx) but the example does not work - the example fails to compile in Visual Studio 2008.